# Extract iframe source in Puppeter sharp

Tags: c#, iframe, puppeteer-sharp

I am scraping web page and trying to extract google adds from the page using Puppeteer Sharp.
Most of them are inside frames.Frame extraction is throwing  "evaluation failed" exception.

```
   var frameElement = await page.EvaluateExpressionAsync<ElementHandle>("google_ads_frame5");
   var frame = await frameElement.ContentFrameAsync();
   var frameContent = await frame.GetContentAsync();
```

[Sample Image of banner and iframe content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcb3o.png)

Answer (score 0):

I would use [WaitForSelectorAsync](https://www.puppeteersharp.com/api/PuppeteerSharp.Page.html#PuppeteerSharp_Page_WaitForSelectorAsync_System_String_PuppeteerSharp_WaitForSelectorOptions_) instead:

```
var frameElement = await page.WaitForSelectorAsync("#google_ads_frame5");
var frame = await frameElement.ContentFrameAsync();
var frameContent = await frame.GetContentAsync();
```

Comment: Not working Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document':' is not a valid selector.

Comment: I tried                         
var expression = "document.getElementById('google_ads_frame5').contentWindow.document.body";
var frameBody = await page.EvaluateExpressionAsync<string>(expression);
getting cross-origin frame error. Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.c-sharpcorner.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame. at <anonymous>:1:104
Any solution I can disable

Comment: Can you share the URL?

Comment: Any google banner animated banner e.g. https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/how-to-read-a-text-file-in-C-Sharp/ left side adds are displayed